# Erro no Comando TASKKILL

Tags: c#, visual-basic-6

Gostaria de fechar um programa quando der erro no meu sistema, para isto estou usando:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM executavel.exe /T
```

Usei para desenvolver uma máquina com W7 e funcionou, porém a do cliente utiliza W10 e não fecha, alguma dica do que pode ser? Permissão, etc?

Comment: você não marca suas perguntas como respondidas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/90864/user90864?tab=questions

Comment: O comando funciona perfeitamente, talvez você esteja tentando finalizar um processo rodando em outro perfil de usuário e não tem o privilégio necessário para isso.